# Как удалить сообщение пользователя в группе ботом телеграмм, содержащее определенный текст?

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot

у бота есть права на удаление сообщений в группе, надо удалять все сообщения содержащие, к примеру, текст "123". Бот на Node.Js, используется node-telegram-bot-api, подскажите?

Comment: `bot.deleteMessage(msg.chat.id, messageId)`

Comment: @nörbörnën не то. я же сказал - все сообщения содержащие слово.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bot.on('message', function (msg) {//при получении сообщения
    var text=msg.text;//получаем текст сообщения
    if( text.indexOf('СЛОВО') >= 0){//проверяем на наличие слова
        var chatId = msg.chat.id;//получаем ChatId группы
        var msgId = msg.message_id;//получаем Id сообщения
        bot.deleteMessage(chatId,msgId);//удаляем сообщение
    }
});
```